# Overwriting Parent Theme's Image Sizes

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails, child-theme, images

I'm using Raw by UDTHEMES as a parent theme for a site I am working on.

In the parent theme, there is the following image size:

`add_image_size( 'udt-full-width-image', 870, 490, true );`

And I am trying to overwrite it in my child theme like so (I have been told that I first need to unset it, and then set it again):

```
// enable post thumbnails
function sgr_filter_image_sizes( $sizes) {
    unset( $sizes['udt-full-width-image']);
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'sgr_filter_image_sizes');

function child_theme_image_size() {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size( 'udt-full-width-image', 870, 9999 );
    add_image_size('background-photo', 1680, 9999);
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'child_theme_image_size', 11 );
```

I've done this and then used the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin, but my images are still displaying at the wrong size.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your `after_setup_theme` action is set to priority 11, what priority does the parent theme use?

Comment: It doesn't appear to have one set actually... I've changed mine to a priority of `0` but still don't seem to be having much luck

Comment: default is 10, so priority 11 *should* be running later than parent theme. is it hooked to `after_setup_theme` in parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the filter. You can just call `add_image_size` later than the parent & it will overwrite.

Comment: That's what I was thinking originally but that didn't appear to work for me either. Won't WP load the parent afterwards and overwrite my image size? Meaning the filter is required to get around it? That's what I've come to understand after reading up on the matter

Comment: So long as you use the `after_setup_theme` hook, your code will fire *after* both your theme & the parent is loaded. The filter is what's shooting you in the foot, as it removes the image size regardless if it's the parent's or your own.